# Intercept Messages from 3rd Party Code

Tags: python, stdout, message, gdal

I am writing a Python script that uses 3rd party modules from `GDAL`.  The `GDAL` functions do not raise exceptions when an error occurs, but do send messages to `stdout`.  Generally, the errors that occur with `GDAL` functions do not warrant stopping the process and I don't need to know about the error having occurred.

Is there a way I can intercept the messages that are being sent to `stdout` before they are printed in the console?  The `GDAL` messages interfere with the messages that I have provided in my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in ["Python Gotchas"](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#PythonbindingsdonotraiseexceptionsunlessyouexplicitlycallUseExceptions), you can turn on Exceptions using `gdal.UseExceptions()`, e.g.:

```
from osgeo import gdal

dsrc = gdal.Open('nonexist')
# ... silence

gdal.UseExceptions()

dsrc = gdal.Open('nonexist')
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
# RuntimeError: `nonexist' does not exist in the file system,
# and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

You could always then use a `try` `except` block get the actual error message string:

```
try:
    dsrc = gdal.Open('nonexist')
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(str(e))
```

which will print the error message:

> `nonexist' does not exist in the file system,
>   and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Comment: I've seen the Python Gotchas and read about `gdal.UseExceptions()`.  What was not clear to me is will that turn on exceptions and turn off the messages or will I get exceptions and messages?

Comment: Basically it turns stderr messages into RuntimeError exceptions, which can be handled in any conceivable way you'd like.